Html Table Expand / Collapse contents does not take up 100% of the width of its parent
I have a table that uses jQuery to expand/collapse rows.  I based it on a site which had a sample on how to do it.
It works fine for that expand / collapse. Outside of WordPress, in a normal website, the expanded table in the row fills the entire width of the parent table.  However, under WordPress it's only 1/2 (50%) of the parent table.
I noticed in the browser debugger the jQuery toggle is changing the <tr class='childTableRow'> to/from: <tr class='childTableRow' style='display: block;'> and <tr class='childTableRow' style='display: none;'>
In the browser debugger, if I changed the style from display: block to display: table-row it correct spans 100% across the parent table.  However, I can't stop jQuery from using display:block.
I couldn't get anything else, including width: 100%, to make it fit the parent table width other than (again in the browser debugger) getting rid of both the class='childTableRow' and the style='display: block'.  At that point expand / collapse still works but jQuery set the style to empty string or none.
Does someone know a way to get this to work properly by just looking at the subset of items below?
The Table:
<table width='100%' class='mytable'>
<tr><th colspan='2' align='center' class='mytitle expandChildTable'>Title</th></tr>
<tr class='childTableRow'><td colspan='2'><table width='100%' class='mytable'>
<tr>
<th align='center' colspan='1' class='mysubtitle'>Left Col Title</th><th align='center' colspan='1' class='mysubtitle'>Right Col Title</th></tr>
<tr><td title='Whatever' align='center' colspan='1' class='mylinks'><a href="/xxxx.htm">Download Me</a></td><td title='Download Link' align='center' colspan='1' class='mylinks'><a href="/xxxxx.htm">Download Me Too</a></td></tr>
     ... repeat as many rows as may be needed ...
<tr><td colspan=2 class='myfooter'>Footer Item</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
</table><br />

The CSS is from wordpress theme (lots of stuff) + these specific for the table:
table.mytable
{
    color:#555555; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    border-width:2px; 
    border-style:solid;  
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    border-color:#777777; 
    table-layout:fixed
}

th.mytitle
{
    color:#ffffff; 
    background-color:#888888; 
    padding:5px; 
    border-width:1px; 
    border-bottom:2px;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-color:#777777;
    text-align: center;
}

th.mysubtitle
{
    background-color:#999999; 
    padding:2px; 
    border-width:1px; 
    border-style:solid; 
    border-color:#777777;
    text-align: center;
}

td.myfooter
{
    background-color:#AAAAAA; 
    padding-left:15px; 
    border-top:1px; 
    border-top-style:solid; 
    border-color:#777777;
}

td.mylinks
{
  padding:2px;
  border-top:0px; 
  border-bottom:0px; 
  border-left:1px; 
  border-right:1px; 
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:#777777;
}

.expandChildTable:before {
    content: "+";
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expandChildTable.selected:before {
    content: "-";
}
.childTableRow {
    display: none;
}

The jQuery used is:
<script src="/include/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.expandChildTable').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').closest('tr').next().toggle();
    })
});
</script>

